# How to query DNN (DotNetNuke) database to find pages that have been recently modified

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I am trying to come up with a sql query that can find all web pages within a DNN website that have been edited recently, but none of the `CreatedOnDate` or `LastModifiedOnDate` values seem terribly useful - for example, the `LastModifiedOnDate` column in the `HtmlText` tables seems to get updated whenever a content editor so much as clicks 'edit' (even if they do not actually make any changes).

For instance, this query returns a lot of urls for pages that have not *actually* been changed since 2018-01-01:

```
select distinct tu.url
from HtmlText ht
join TabModules tm
    on ht.moduleid = tm.moduleid
join Modules m
    on tm.moduleid = m.moduleid
join Tabs t
    on tm.tabid = t.tabid
join TabUrls tu
    on t.tabid = tu.tabid
where ht.LastModifiedOnDate >= '2018-01-01'
```

Is there some place that I don't know about in the database where changes are tracked more accurately?

**edit**

It turns out the best way to find pages that have changed in a DNN web site is to join on the TabVersions table, e.g.:

```
select distinct replace(t.tabpath, '//', '/'), u.email, u.displayname
from HtmlText ht
join TabModules tm
    on ht.moduleid = tm.moduleid
join Tabs t
    on tm.tabid = t.tabid
join TabVersions tv
    on t.TabID = tv.tabid
join Users u
    on tv.createdbyuserid = u.userid
where tv.CreatedOnDate >= '2018-03-01'
```

Comment: If a true modification date isn't tracked, I'm not sure how you'd be able to get an accurate list of last modifications.

Comment: good point, shawn - I added the question "Is there some place that I don't know about in the database where changes are tracked more accurately?" to clarify what I am asking.

Comment: I'm not sure how editable DNN is, but you may have to change the code on the `edit` operation to not mark the `LastModifiedOnDate` until that edit is actually submitted. That may be something they discussed on their forums as to why it's like that or if that's just a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Modification dates are tracked for every Tab, TabModule Settings and Module Contents (depending on the Module itself). Even the HTMLText. 
And yes, the dates are updated when the Update Button is pressed, regardless of actual changes made to the settings or contents.

However the LastModifiedOnDate is not updated just by opening the Settings.

And your query seems incorrect. I ran it and it did not return the latest HTMLText that I modified. Only when removing the Inner Join on the TabUrls were all modules returned. So I would do this:

```
SELECT HtmlText.ModuleID, TabModules.ModuleTitle, Tabs.TabName, TabUrls.Url 
  FROM HtmlText 
  INNER JOIN TabModules ON TabModules.ModuleID = HtmlText.ModuleID 
  INNER JOIN Tabs ON Tabs.TabID = TabModules.TabID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TabUrls ON TabUrls.TabId = Tabs.TabID
  ORDER BY HtmlText.LastModifiedOnDate DESC
```